# Is a projection from a conic to itself through a point a projective transformation?

Tags: geometry, transformation, projective-geometry, projection

> Given a conic $C$ is the map For $A\in C,$ $A\to AX\cap C$ Where we take the point which isn't $A$.(except when $AX$ is a tangent) a projective transformation from the conic to itself? where $X$ is a fixed point not on $C$

I'm pretty sure the statement is correct but I've been unable to find a source for it.
I have a proof sketch but I'm unsure whether it is actually true:
Project $C$ to be a circle and $X$ it's center, then the transform is just a rotation which is projective.
Is this argument true?

Comment: Even if the conic is non-degenerate, the line $\overline{AX}$ might intersect $C$ in more than one point.

Comment: 1) I understand that $X$ is a fixed point ? Why don't you say it ? 2) I think you mean a **homography** $s \to (at+b)/(ct+d)$ for a certain parametrication from the conic curve to itself.

Comment: One of the intersection points is A, So we take the other one(of course, if it's tangent we take A)

Comment: 1) Yes, it is a fixed point, I'll edit it in 2) Yes

Comment: You should add $A\in C$ if you mean it. One can define it so: $(A\in C) \to B: B\in (AX\cap C) \land |AB|=\rm{max}$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your proof is fine.

For an alternative proof note that the mapping $T$ you give extends to the entire plane.  For any point $P$, take any two lines $\ell, m$ passing through $P$ that are secants to $C$.  You can find the intersections of the secants with $C$ and use the mapping to find lines $\ell',m'$ whose intersection gives $F'=T(F)$.

$T$ is a perspective mapping whose center is $S$ and whose axis is the polar of S. So $C$ is in perspective with itself.

This is covered in lots of old (19th and early 20th century) textbooks, e.g. [Hatton's *Projective Geometry*, pg 173 (o)](https://archive.org/details/principlesofproj00hattuoft/page/172/mode/2up?view=theater).  That reference refers back to [Article 79](https://archive.org/details/principlesofproj00hattuoft/page/136/mode/2up?view=theater) in the same text.

Comment: @razivo - is this not what you were looking for?